# error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[20]'

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The code:

```
struct
{
    char firstname[10];
    char lastname[10];
    char passfail[20];
    int score;
}student_mark;  

/*Get student details*/

printf("Hello user, please enter your forename\n");
scanf("%s", student_mark.firstname);

printf("\n..and your surname?\n");
scanf("%s", student_mark.lastname);

printf("\n\nHow about your mark out of 10 for the year?\n");
scanf("%d", &student_mark.score);

if (student_mark.score >= 8)
    {
        student_mark.passfail="DISTINCTION\n";
    }
else if (student_mark.score >= 6)
    {
        student_mark.passfail="PASS\n";
    }
else if(student_mark.score <=5)
    {
        student_mark.passfail="FAIL\n";
    }

printf("First name = %s\n", student_mark.firstname);
printf("Last name = %s\n", student_mark.lastname);
printf("Achieved: = %s\n", student_mark.passfail);

return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, it gives me the warning: incompatible types when assigning to type `char[20]` from type `char * student_mark.passfail="DISTINCTION\n";`

Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shall not use `=` operator while *copying* strings. You need to use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy).

For your reference, the `student_mark.passfail` is a statically allocated array. by using

```
student_mark.passfail="DISTINCTION\n";
```

What you're trying to do is to copy the base address of the string `"DISTINCTION\n"` to `student_mark.passfail` variable. However, this is not possible, as you cannot change the address of a statically allocated variable.

OTOH, if `student_mark.passfail` would have been defined as a `char` pointer instead of a `char` array, then it would have been allowed to do

```
student_mark.passfail="DISTINCTION\n";
```

because, there you would have been using the `student_mark.passfail` *pointer* to hold the base address of the string `"DISTINCTION\n"`.

Comment: Yes, and the reason behind the downvote please, anyone?

Comment: it seems that some guys have just enough reputation to Just downvote for no reason. They don't leave a comment explaining why. What bothers me is that then there is no way to know what is wrong with an answer that got it downvotes, here goes un upvote, with a comment.

Comment: @iharob Really appreciate your effort. Maybe the _error_ is too obvious to the downvoter, but the real issue here is the newbie learners, like _us_ are unable to pinpoint the errors. I would really look forward to receive a comment against each downvote. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly assign value to the variable. You can use the strcpy function or sprintf function.

```
strcpy(char *dest,char *src);

sprintf(student_mark.passfail,"DISTINCTION\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign to an array, in C you have to copy the contents of the string into the array using `strcpy` this way

```
strcpy(student_mark.passfail, "DISTINCTION\n");
```

you must be very careful that the length of the source string is not larger than that of the destination string.